# Code with regex seems to end for no reason

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have written a piece of code to 'compile' a file (mostly for my own practice). It first loads all the lines form the file into RAM, and then reads the file. To understand what is written in it, I have used regular expressions with the `String.matches()` and `String.contains()` methods. Now I came across a really weird problem, something I never had before: the program ends without any good reason for it. It doesn't give an error or exception, or any other indicator something might be wrong.

This is the part I am talking about:

```
else if (s.contains("interface")) {
    if (s.matches("\\s*interface\\s*{\\s*")) {  //The program seems to stop on this line
        logger.info("Found properties block opener on line " + (i + 1) + ": " + s);

    }
    else if (s.matches("\\s*interface\\s*")) {
        if (lines[i + 1].matches("\\s*{\\s*")) {
            logger.info("Found properties block opener on lines " + (i + 1) + " and " + (i + 2) + ": " + s);

        }

    }

}
```

`s` is the `String` to search, `lines[i + 1]` is the next line and I created a logger object to log the compiling.

Using the debugger in Eclipse, I found out that when it comes to the line with the comment, it jumps to the `Pattern` class, and then just stops. I mean that it opens a new tab with the source for the `Pattern` class, and the next step it terminates, without giving any logical reason, or any reason at all.

Is there something wrong with my regex? (it tries to search for a string like this: `interface {` and the `else if` statement looks for the alternative:

```
interface
{
```

I tried to restart Eclipse as I thought that there might be a problem there, but it didn't help.

If more code is required, just post a comment to tell me.

Comment: And is "s" only "interface {", or does it contains something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{` is a special meta regex character that needs to be escaped. Use this regex:

```
s.matches("\\s*interface\\s*\\{\\s*")
```

Comment: Used to define [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), i.e. `.{1,3}`